# Correct Try...Catch Syntax Using Async/Await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch, ecmascript-2017

I like the flatness of the new `Async/Await` feature available in Typescript, etc. However, I'm not sure I like the fact that I have to declare the variable I'm `await`ing on the outside of a `try...catch` block in order to use it later. Like so:

```
let createdUser
try {
    createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo)
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}

console.log(createdUser)
// business
// logic
// goes
// here
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to be best practice *not* to place multiple lines of business logic in the `try` body, so I'm left only with the alternative of declaring `createdUser` outside the block, assigning it in the block, and then using it after.

What is best practice in this instance?

Comment: "Best practice" is to use what works and is understandable, maintainable, etc.. How could we answer this question "correctly"? I'd just use `var`, knowing the variable would be hoisted. Is that "wrong"?

Comment: try/catch should enclose exactly what you want to capture an exception for. If you're looking explicitly for errors coming from `this.User.create()` then you wouldn't put anything else inside the try/catch.  But, it's also a perfectly reasonable design to put a whole bunch of logic inside a try block. It all depends upon how/where you want to handle an error and how you want to design your exception handling code and what makes sense for a given operation.  There is no generic best practice.  The ONE generic best practice is to make sure you catch and handle all errors in some appropriate way.

Comment: `async/await` is part of **ES2017** (this year's release), not ES6 (which was released two years ago).

Comment: To add to @jfriend00's comment, if you put your business logic inside the `try` block, and that code `Error`s, (`TypeError`, `ReferenceError`, etc), that will be `catch`ed, which could produce unexpected behavior if you're expecting to only `catch` promise rejections.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

> It seems to be best practice not to place multiple lines of business logic in the try body

Actually I'd say it is. You usually want to `catch` *all* exceptions from working with the value:

```
try {
    const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo);

    console.log(createdUser)
    // business logic goes here
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error) // from creation or business logic
}
```

If you want to catch and handle errors only from the promise, you have three choices:

- Declare the variable outside, and branch depending on whether there was an exception or not. That can take various forms, like

  - assign a default value to the variable in the `catch` block
  - `return` early or re-`throw` an exception from the `catch` block
  - set a flag whether the `catch` block caught an exception, and test for it in an `if` condition
  - test for the value of the variable to have been assigned

  ```
    let createdUser; // or use `var` inside the block
    try {
        createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error) // from creation
    }
    if (createdUser) { // user was successfully created
        console.log(createdUser)
        // business logic goes here
    }
  ```
- Test the caught exception for its type, and handle or rethrow it based on that.

  ```
    try {
        const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo);
        // user was successfully created
        console.log(createdUser)
        // business logic goes here
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof CreationError) {
            console.error(error) // from creation
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
  ```

  Unfortunately, standard JavaScript (still) doesn't have syntax support for [conditional exceptions](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/try-catch-conditional-exceptions-in-light-of-generators).

  If your method doesn't return promises that are rejected with specific enough errors, you can do that yourself by re-throwing something more appropriate in a `.catch()` handler:

  ```
    try {
        const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo).catch(err => {
            throw new CreationError(err.message, {code: "USER_CREATE"});
        });
        …
    } …
  ```

  See also [Handling multiple catches in promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26076511/1048572) for the pre-`async`/`await` version of this.
- Use [`then` with two callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) instead of `try`/`catch`. This really is the least ugly way and my personal recommendation also for its simplicity and correctness, not relying on tagged errors or looks of the result value to distinguish between fulfillment and rejection of the promise:

  ```
    await this.User.create(userInfo).then(createdUser => {
        // user was successfully created
        console.log(createdUser)
        // business logic goes here
    }, error => {
        console.error(error) // from creation
    });
  ```

  Of course it comes with the drawback of introducing callback functions, meaning you cannot as easily `break`/`continue` loops or do early `return`s from the outer function.

Comment: Your last example uses `.then()` to resolve the promise and provide a callback, so perhaps `await` has no effect there.

Comment: @dcorking It is `await`ing the promise returned by the `.then(…)` call.

Comment: do the lambdas returned by the `.then()` call need the async keyword?

Comment: @dcorking Only if they use `await` inside.

Comment: I have seen people attaching catch handler directly to await . Is it a good Idea to do that or wrap it inside try/catch?

Comment: @Saroj `const result = await something().catch(err => fallback);` is simpler than `let result; try { result = await something(); } catch(err) { result = fallback; }` so yes in that case I consider it a good idea.

Comment: @Bergi any downsides to this syntax? For example, how would one break out of the surrounding scope? Attaching the handler seems to be the most concise yet flexible approach.

Comment: @Slaiyer What do you mean by "*break out of the surrounding scope*"? Sure, you can't place a `break` keyword in the `onreject` callback of `then`/`catch`, if you need to break from a loop go with a traditional `try` block. If you refer to returning a value to the surrounding scope, just `return` it from the callback and `await` the promise chain.

Answer (score 40):

Another simpler approach is to append .catch to the promise function. ex:

```
const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo).catch( error => {
// handle error
})
```

Comment: I had never thought of this, but I tried it out, and it has an interesting side effect: you can `return` a result in the `.catch()` callback to set the value. Otherwise, it returns undefined.

Comment: This is mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#rewriting_a_promise_chain_with_an_async_function)

Answer (score 13):

### Cleaner code

#### using async/await with Promise catch handler.

From what I see, this has been a long-standing problem that has bugged (both meanings) many programmers and their code. The Promise `.catch` is really no different from `try/catch`.

ES6 Promise's catch handler and work harmoniously with "await/async", providing a proper solution and cleaner code:

```js
const createUser = await this.User
    .create(userInfo)
    .catch(error => console.error(error))

console.log(createdUser)
// business
// logic
// goes
// here
```

Note that while this answers the question, it gobbles up the error. In this case, it is better to throw because (1) this operation (creating a user) is not expected to failed, and (2) you not able to continue anyway -- the operation has errored out:

```js
const createUser = await this.User
    .create(userInfo)
    .catch(error => {
        // do what you need with the error
        console.error(error)

        // maybe send to Datadog or Sentry

        // don't gobble up the error
        throw error
    })

console.log(createdUser)
// business
// logic
// goes
// here
```

### Learning `catch` doesn't seem like worth it?

The cleanliness benefits may not be apparent above, but it adds up in real-world complex async operations.

As an illustration, besides creating user (`this.User.create`), we can push notification (`this.pushNotification`) and send email (`this.sendEmail`).

**this.User.create**

```js
this.User.create = async(userInfo) => {

    // collect some fb data and do some background check in parallel
    const facebookDetails = await retrieveFacebookAsync(userInfo.email)
        .catch(error => {
            // we can do some special error handling

            // and throw back the error
         })
    const backgroundCheck = await backgroundCheckAsync(userInfo.passportID)

    if (backgroundCheck.pass !== true) throw Error('Background check failed')

    // now we can insert everything
    const createdUser = await Database.insert({ ...userInfo, ...facebookDetails })

    return createdUser
}
```

**this.pushNotifcation** and **this.sendEmail**

```js
this.pushNotification = async(userInfo) => {
    const pushed = await PushNotificationProvider.send(userInfo)
    return pushed
})

this.sendEmail = async(userInfo) => {
    const sent = await mail({ to: userInfo.email, message: 'Welcome' })
    return sent
})
```

Compose the operations:

```js
const createdUser = await this.User
    .create(userInfo)
    .catch(error => {
        // handle error
    })

// business logic here

return await Promise.all([
    this.pushNotification(userInfo),
    this.sendEmail(userInfo)
]).catch(error => {
    // handle errors caused
    // by pushNotification or sendEmail
})
```

No try/catch. And it's clear what errors you are handling.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the Promise's `catch()` function to return an object with an `error` property on failure.

For example, in your case i'd do:

```js
const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo)
          .catch(error => { error }); // <--- the added catch

if (Object(createdUser).error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

If you don't like to keep adding the `catch()` calls, you can add a helper function to the Function's prototype:

```js
Function.prototype.withCatcher = function withCatcher() {
    const result = this.apply(this, arguments);
    if (!Object(result).catch) {
        throw `${this.name}() must return a Promise when using withCatcher()`;
    }
    return result.catch(error => ({ error }));
};
```

And now you'll be able to do:

```js
const createdUser = await this.User.create.withCatcher(userInfo);
if (Object(createdUser).error) {
    console.error(createdUser.error);
}
```

---

EDIT 03/2020

You can also add a default "catch to an error object" function to the `Promise` object like so:

```js
Promise.prototype.catchToObj = function catchToObj() {
    return this.catch(error => ({ error }));
};
```

And then use it as follows:

```js
const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo).catchToObj();
if (createdUser && createdUser.error) {
    console.error(createdUser.error);
}
```

Comment: I use the last approach and it gives me `'catchToObj' is not a function` error.

Comment: @newguy `catchToObj` will exist on every `Promise` object after you call the first code segment in my answer. If your function doesn't return a `Promise` it won't work

Comment: I am using the Sequelize's `create` method which returns a `Promise<Model>`.                   definition is : `public static async create(values: object, options: object): Promise<Model>`

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi Answer is good, but I think it's not the best way because you have to go back to the old then() method, so i think a better way is to catch the error in the async function

```
async function someAsyncFunction(){
    const createdUser = await this.User.create(userInfo);

    console.log(createdUser)
}

someAsyncFunction().catch(console.log);
```

- But what if we have many `await` in the same function and need to catch every error?

You may declare the `to()` function

```
function to(promise) {
    return promise.then(data => {
        return [null, data];
    })
    .catch(err => [err]);
}
```

And then

```
async function someAsyncFunction(){
    let err, createdUser, anotherUser;

    [err, createdUser] = await to(this.User.create(userInfo));

    if (err) console.log(`Error is ${err}`);
    else console.log(`createdUser is ${createdUser}`);


    [err, anotherUser] = await to(this.User.create(anotherUserInfo));

    if (err) console.log(`Error is ${err}`);
    else console.log(`anotherUser is ${anotherUser}`);
}

someAsyncFunction();
```

> When reading this its: "Wait to this.User.create".

Finally you can create the module "to.js" or simply use the [await-to-js](https://github.com/scopsy/await-to-js) module.

You can get more information about `to` function in [this post](https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/)

Comment: `then` isn't worse than `await` because it older. It's just different, and suited for other things. This "`await to(…)` style" on the other hand is reminiscent of the nodeback style with all its disadvantages.

Comment: Btw, for better performance and simplicity you should use `promise.then(data => [null, data], err => [err, null]);`

Comment: Exactly "It's just different, and suited for other things" `await` is used for create a code with a "synchronous" like syntax, the use of `then` and it's callback is more asynchronous syntax. Btw thanks for the code simplicity recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
await this.User.create(userInfo).then(async data => await this.emailService.sendEmail(data.email), async error => await this.sentryService.sendReport(error))
```

Comment: This is just an example of how I would use async/await/catch. The .then() block has two callbacks: first, if this.User.create() resolves, and if it doesn't.