# nesting async/await javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

Is this valid async/await logic: calling try/catch from within another try/catch?

```
//within async function...

try { 
    await asyncFunctionFirst();
    } catch (errFirst) {
          try {
              await asyncFunctionSecond();              
          } catch (errSecond) {
              // return errSecond response
          }
      //return errFirst response          
    } 
//return response ok
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the approach is ok or there is more elegant solution that I'm missing.

Comment: No that is the most elegant approach possible (assuming you need to call those methods/perform that logic). The purpose of `async`/`await` is precisely to enable asynchronously logic to be expressed in this fashion.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await 'The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.' so, I guess it is valid. Have you tested if it runs?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid syntax. However I would not write it like this. Rather use

```
try { 
    await asyncFunctionFirst();
    return …; // response ok 
} catch (errFirst) {
    try {
        await asyncFunctionSecond();
        return …; // errFirst response
    } catch (errSecond) {
        return …; // errSecond response
    }
}
```

(if you would also want to catch exceptions from the `…` parts - if not, your version is fine, for alternatives see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572))