# How can I stop execution of an outer function within a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Lets imagine I have a scenario like this:

```
async function some_func() {
  await some_query.catch(async (e) => {
    await some_error_code()
  })

  console.log('The above function ran without an error')
}
```

I only wish for the `console.log()` to be reached if the asynchronous function ran successfully.  At the moment, my solution is:

```
async function some_func() {
  let did_error = false
  await some_query.catch(async (e) => {
    await some_error_code()
    did_error = true
  })

  if (did_error) return

  console.log('The above function ran without an error')
}
```

But that's not great.  Is there any way of handling this without the added bulk?  Similar to multiple for loops:

```
outer: for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    continue outer;
  }
  console.log('Never called')
}
```

Comment: Just use `then` instead of `catch`? Have a look at [Correct Try…Catch Syntax Using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a better way, you can use the return value within the catch function:

```
async function some_func() {
  let response = await some_query.catch(async (e) => {
    await some_error_code()
    return { err: 'some_error_code' }
  })

  if (response.err) return

  console.log('The above function ran without an error')
}
```

However this still isn't great, not sure if there's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually write either

```
function some_func() {
  return some_query().then(res => {
    console.log('The above function ran without an error')
  }, (e) => {
    return some_error_code()
  })
}
```

or

```
async function some_func() {
  try {
    await some_query()
  } catch(e) {
    await some_error_code()
    return
  }
  console.log('The above function ran without an error')
}
```

> But that's not great. Is there any way of handling this similar to multiple for loops

Yes, it's also possible to use a block:

```
async function some_func() {
  noError: {
    try {
      await some_query()
    } catch(e) {
      await some_error_code()
      break noError
    }
    console.log('The above function ran without an error')
  }
  console.log('This will always run afterwards')
}
```