# async / await proper error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, sequelize.js

Assume we have an action that runs on user login (express, node). 
This is the code that works, written using a lot of callbacks:

```
checkIfEmailAndPasswordAreSet(email, password, (error, response) => {
  if (error) return errorResponse(403, 'validation error', error)
  findUserByEmail(email, (error, user) => {
    if (error) return errorResponse(500, 'db error', error)
    if (!user) return errorResponse(403, 'user not found')
    checkUserPassword(user, password, (error, result) => {
      if (error) return errorResponse(500, 'bcrypt error', error)
      if (!result) return errorResponse(403, 'incorrect password')
      updateUserLastLoggedIn(user, (error, response) => {
        if (error) return errorResponse(500, 'db error', error)      
        generateSessionToken(user, (error, token) => {
          if (error) return errorResponse(500, 'jwt error', error)
          return successResponse(user, token)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I want to rewrite this code using async/await and avoid callback hell. How to do that?

The first attempt could look like that:

```
try {
  await checkIfEmailAndPasswordAreSet(email, password)
  const user = await findUserByEmail(email)
  if (!user) throw new Error('user not found')
  const result = await checkUserPassword(user, password)
  if (!result) throw new Error('incorrect password')
  await updateUserLastLoggedIn(user)
  const token = await generateSessionToken(user)
  return successResponse(user, token)
} catch (e) {
  // How to handle the error here?
}
```

I want to keep the proper error handling, that is if the error was thrown in `checkUserPassword` method, I want the response to contain info about this. What should I write in the catch method?

For example, I could wrap every instruction into it's own try / catch block like that:

```
try {

  let user, result

  try {
    await checkIfEmailAndPasswordAreSet(email, password)
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('This error was thrown in checkIfEmailAndPasswordAreSet')
  }

  try {
    user = await findUserByEmail(email)
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('This error was thrown in findUserByEmail')
  }

  if (!user) throw new Error('user not found')

  ...
} catch (error) {
  return errorResponse(error)
}
```

But this code.. probably that's not a callback hell, but I would call it try/catch hell. It takes at least 2 times more rows that the original old fashioned code with callbacks. How to rewrite it to be shorter and take an advantage of async/await?

Comment: You can add specific error types , like `throw new UserNotFoundError` instead of `new Error('user not found')` and then do some `instanceof` branching in the catch block.

Comment: `it takes at least 2 more rows` ... cool. But its definetly more readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no [easy handling of individual errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await) with `try`/`catch`.

I would probably write some helper functions to facilitate simple error throwing:

```
function error(code, msg) {
    return e => {
        e.status = code;
        e.details = msg;
        throw e;
    };
}
function ifEmpty(fn) {
    return o => o || fn(new Error("empty"));
}
```

and then use standard promise methods:

```
try {
    await checkIfEmailAndPasswordAreSet(email, password)
        .catch(error(403, 'validation error'));
    const user = await findUserByEmail(email)
        .then(ifEmpty(error(403, 'user not found')), error(500, 'db error', error));
    await checkUserPassword(user, password)
        .then(ifEmpty(error(403, 'incorrect password')), error(500, 'bcrypt error'));
    await updateUserLastLoggedIn(user)
        .catch(error(500, 'db error'));
    const token = generateSessionToken(user)
        .catch(error(500, 'jwt error'));
    return successResponse(user, token);
} catch(err) {
    errorResponse(err.status, err.details, err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I used your approach and the code looks prettier now, imho. Will mark as answer in several days if no other response.

Comment: Yeah, prettiness is in the eye of the beholder :-) You might also write different helper functions that operate on promises and could be called like `await rejectEmpty(wrapRejection(checkPassword(…), 500, 'bcrypt'), 403, 'password')`. Any abstraction that makes the code DRY will do :-)