# Call/apply/bind with await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to work with a callback based API, but I would like to retain my async functions. That's why I'm trying to write a depromisify function:

```js
const depromisify = fn => {
  if (!(fn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction')) {
    return fn;
  }

  // Can be `async` as the caller won't use assignment to get the result - it's all bound to the `cb`
  return async function () {
    const args = [...arguments];
    const cb = args.pop();

    try {
      return cb(null, await fn.apply(this, args));
    } catch (e) {
      return cb(e);
    }
  };
};

const normal = function(cb) {
  this.hello();
  cb(null, true);
};

const promised = async function() {
  this.hello();
  return true;
};

function Usual(fn) {
  this.random = 'ABC';
  fn.call(this, (err, result, info) => {
    console.log((err && err.message) || null, result);
  });
};

Usual.prototype.hello = () => {
  console.log('hello!');
};

new Usual(normal);
new Usual(depromisify(promised));
```

However it won't work when I try to depromisify an arrow function, as you can't bind anything to it:

```
new Usual(depromisify(async () => {
  this.hello();
  return false;
}));
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async await` but that arrow functions are different to "regular" functions; at least in some regards. This code would not work like that, even if it was sync: `new Usual(() => {
  this.hello();
  return false;
});`

Comment: Arrow functions can't be used as methods. There's no way out (apart from not using the `this` keyword, as in `var x = new Usual(() => x.hello())`, which of course won't work if `Usual` calls the function before it returns the instance).

Comment: Btw, your `depromisify` is broken as it will run the callback twice when it throws a second time. Use [`.then(…, …)` with two callbacks instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572): `function depromisify(fn) { return function(...args) { var cb = args.pop(); fn.apply(this, args).then(v => cb(null, v), e => cb(e)).catch(e => void e); }; }`

Comment: @Bergi Sorry about the duplicate, but what exactly do you have in mind with `throws a second time`? Reading the thread you linked, it does not seem like that is an equivalent situation, the `fn` can't throw twice, unless the wrapper itself throws an exception and there is no assignment to a value outside of `try...catch`

Comment: Oops, messed up that sentence. I meant to say: it will run the callback a second time when it throws during the first call. Your `catch` should not handle exceptions from `cb`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. No solution. Arrow functions are a bit special in that regard.

Here is the quote from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description):

> Two factors influenced the introduction of arrow functions: shorter
>   functions and non-binding of this.

Comment: I thought so. I will accept the answer tommorow unless someone comes up with some magic solution, thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news. How long can you hold your breath :-)

Comment: @Misiur Black magic with `eval` can do anything. You won't like it though.

Comment: You mean like working with stringified contents of the function?

Comment: @Bergi https://jsfiddle.net/b2pe0zq0/ - this is weird

Comment: @Misiur Yes. And "weird" is a very soft word. There are so many pitfalls (you'll discover the first if you try to use `await` in the function).

Comment: @Misiur, I will always defer to Bergi, but I'm still getting that check mark!  hehe.