# promise chaining over async await - javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If we're not concerned with browser compatibility issues.

Is there ever a situation where you would opt for `.then()` chaining rather then an `async/await` implementation?

Comment: When you want to [use the second argument to `then`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). It's really [hard to reproduce with `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572).

Comment: `async`/`await` is just syntax sugar. There is nothing you can do with async await that you can't do with promises and vice versa.

Comment: How would you achieve `Promise.all`?