# Async - await not working nodeJS with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, async-await

Comparing the password on user login request. Used **async and await** to wait till get the actual response.

I expect it to run on following order 1,2,3,4 (order of console.log)

but it executes as 1, 3, 4, 2. Please help.

script does not wait for **comparePassword**

```
async login(request){
        let response =  await User.findOne({ email: request.email }, async (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('1');

            let isMatch =  await user.comparePassword(request.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                console.log('2');
                if (err) throw err;
                request.isMatch = isMatch;
            });

            console.log('3');
            return request;

        });

        console.log('4');
        console.log('response', response);
    }
```

Comment: `await user.comparePassword` is executing asynchronously. Can you show your comparePassword method?

Comment: thanks found the issue, you saved my day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `async`/`await`, you are using promises, and you must not pass a callback to the mongoose methods. If you don't pass one, they will return a promise that you can `await`. You are looking for

```
async login(request){
    let response =  await User.findOne({ email: request.email });
    console.log('1');
    let isMatch =  await user.comparePassword(request.password);
    console.log('2');
    request.isMatch = isMatch;
    console.log('3');
    return request;
    console.log('4');
    console.log('response', response);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can put a `try` block around `await`, or use good ol' `.catch()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await