# Can all JavaScript promises be rewritten to use async await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

All async/await code can be translated to Promises, or other constructs. Because this is what transpilation with babel has done.

I has assumed the two paradigms where equivalent and that all promises could be rewritten with async/await. Is this true? Or is it an assumption I need to drop.

For a concrete example I have the following code, which contains a promise.
I have not seen a way to translate this code to async/await only.

*For context, this Mailbox code is for a demo I have to explain the Actor model in the context of the browser/JavaScript*

```
function Mailbox () {
  const messages = []
  var awaiting = undefined

  this.receive = () => {
    if (awaiting) { throw 'Mailbox alread has a receiver'}
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (next = messages.shift()) {
        resolve(next)
      } else {
        awaiting = resolve
      }
    })
  }

  this.deliver = async (message) => {
    messages.push(message)
    if (awaiting) {
      awaiting(messages.shift())
      awaiting = undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that `await` can replace `.then`s - you can't meaningfully *construct* a `Promise` with only `async`/`await`

Comment: [`then` with two callbacks is hard to replace with `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572).

Comment: Why is `deliver` an `async` function? There's no reason for it to return a promise. On the other hand, `receive` should be marked as `async` to always return a promise (or you should change the `throw …` into a `return Promise.reject(…)`).

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` use promises.  In fact, they don't do anything useful if you don't have a promise to `await`.  They don't replace promises.  You would typically use `await` instead of `.then()` on a promise.

Let's look at a simple example.   Suppose you have two functions that return promises.

```
 function delay(t) {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(resolve, t);
     });
 }

 const rp = require('request-promise');

 function getData(uri) {
     let options = {uri, json: true};
     return rp(options);
 }
```

Now, you want to get data from three different URLs with a 1 second delay between the requests.

**Regular Promises**

With regular promises (no async/await), you could do something like this using promise chaining:

```
function getAllData() {
    let result = {};
    return getData(firstURL).then(data => {
        results.d1 = data;
        return delay(1000);
    }).then(() => {
        return getData(secondURL);
    }).then(data => {
        results.d2 = data;
        return delay(1000);
    }).then(() => {
       return getData(thirdURL);
    }).then(data => {
       results.d3 = data;
       return results;
    });
}

getAllData().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

**Using Async/Await**

Using `await`, you can simplify the sequencing of multiple asynchronous operations, but those asynchronous operations STILL use promises.  You are just replacing some of the chained `.then()` operations with `await`.

```
async function getAllData() {
   let result = {};
   result.d1 = await getData(firstURL);
   await delay(1000);
   result.d2 = await getData(secondURL);
   await delay(1000);
   result.d3 = await getData(thirdURL);
   await delay(1000);
   return result;
}

getAllData().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```