# Scenario where to async/await over Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I know that async/await are essentially the same under the hood (at least in V8). I've used both extensively and I noticed that I avoid async/await more and more. I also noted a significant decrease in momentum whenever I was forced to write code based on async/await.

• Are there scenarios in which async/await is objectively better than Promises?

• ...If not, why do some stick to async/await?

• What option should be used for flow control? Does this depend on the length of the flow?

• Is there a clear choice if the goal is to produce code that's easy to read and understand?

Comment: You always use promises, regardless of what syntax you use for them. Make sure you have understood promises, and that `await` is a replacement for `then` calls only. There hardly is any scenario where not using `await` is simpler. You might want to show us some code where you found `then` easier to use, explain your reasoning, and show us how you struggled with getting an equivalent `async`/`await` version of the code.

Comment: @plalx No, it's syntactic sugar for promise `then` calls specifically. And it doesn't allow to deal with synchronous processes either - it allows making asynchronous processes *sequential* easily, though.

Comment: Try using `await` in a for loop and then try to change that to strictly use Promises. It's hard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an awesome article about that by *Gokul N K* which I agree with pretty much:

https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789

From my point of you, I'd say `async/await` is just better in terms of waiting for promise resolves (async function returns promises, btw).

For example, I use `async/await` more frequent in node environment when I call async function that manipulate data (DB or 3rd party API). Like:

```
// server

async function removeComment(commentId) {
  const comment = await getComment(commentId);

  if (comment) {
    const commentAuthorUserId = await getUser(comment.userId);
    notifyUser(commentAuthorUserId);

    await removedCommentFromDB(comment);
    res.json({ status: 'ok' });
  }
}
```

The code above is not real, but shows how cool the code looks without multiple `then` nesting. Btw, use `try ... catch` for error handling when you use `await` many times (more than twice) in one `async` function. Otherwise, you can use `.catch()` for await promise as @Bergi mentioned.

In other hand, I use Promises in browser to control flow, but not manipulating data.

For example:

```
// client

function onRemoveClick(commentId) {
  service.removeComment(commentId).then(() => {
    DOM.removeCommentElement(commentId);
  });
}
```

because If I'd use `await` it turns into:

```
async function onRemoveClick(commentId) {
  const response = await service.removeComment(commentId);

  if (response.status === 'ok') {
    DOM.removeCommentElement(commentId);
  }
}
```

which is a quite longer and also it always resolves a HTTP Response which is not obvious for the first glance.

Comment: "*always use `try ... catch` for error handling when you use `async/await`.*" - [I can not quite agree on the "always"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi you are right, for a single `async` call or scoped error handling you'd want to user `catch` for await promise, but it ruins the whole beauty of `async/await` flatness. Edited.

Comment: Yeah, just saying that in some cases you want a non-flat control flow, and then `try` gets in the way.

Comment: Sometimes (especially DB manipulation in node), I just don't use either. I jsut set error handling hooks and write much cleaner code and in case error happen server just returns 500 Error and I then I can see the actual error in logs