# Catch Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, webdriver-io

I am running a test using WebdriverIO and precisely on this line:

```
await browser.waitForVisible('#tx-sent li', 15000)
```

Every now and then, I get a Promise rejection error:

> Error: Promise was rejected with the following reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer (connect failed)

Is there a way to catch this promise rejection so that it doesn't cause the entire test to fail? In other words I want to catch this Promise rejection and resolve it.

Comment: `try { ... } catch (ex) { ... }`

Comment: [Correct Try…Catch Syntax Using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await)

Comment: @Andreas and if I want to include multiple 'await' lines of code in the try block, that's fine, right?

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't do it... One `try...catch...` per `await`, or the `await ...then(value => { ... }, error => { ... })` approach from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await).

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it? The thing is, this error randomly occurs in one of the await lines, and I think it makes more sense to group this all into a try catch block rather than using one for each await line.

Comment: Grouping all promises in one block will stop the execution of other promises once error occurs in  any one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try/catch

```
try {
        await browser.waitForVisible('#tx-sent li', 15000);
} catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and catch to handle errors in promises. do something like this

```
try {
   await browser.waitForVisible('#tx-sent li', 15000)
   } catch(error) {
  // thro or log erro as per you need
  //throw error;
   console.log(error);
 }
```