# How to properly catch exception from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon

#### Problem

My `try` doesn't `catch` error if it is inside of MongoClients `connect` function

---

#### Environment

- Linux (Mint, Tessa)
- Node.js v10.16.0 (using ES6 with **nodemon**)
- MongoClient (from mongodb npm repository)

---

### Example

If I try this:

```
try {
    throw new Error('This is error');
} catch(e) {
    console.log(`Catched: ${e}`);
}
```

I get **clean exit** (it's fine - working)

```
Catched: Error: This is error
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

#### But this doesn't work

If I try it in MongoDBs connect function:

```
try {
   MongoClient.connect(config.url, config.options, (err, db) => {
      if (err) { throw new Error('This is error'); }
   });
} catch (err) {
   console.log(`Catched: ${e}`);
}
```

I get **app crashed**

```
Error: This is error
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So it means it didn't catch my exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
   let db = await MongoClient.connect(config.url, config.options);
} catch (err) {
   console.log(`Catched: ${err}`);
}
```

Try to write code in `async-await/sequential` style if you want try catch to work.

Here you can see that you're getting `err` as first argument in callback, why would it go to catch block ? Same thing happens with `func1().then().catch()` style code.

> Note: use async keyword in front of your function name if you want to use await.

eg:

```
async function test() {
   try {
   let db = await MongoClient.connect(config.url, config.options);
} catch (err) {
   console.log(`Catched: ${err}`);
} 
}

MongoClient.connect(config.url, config.options, (err, db) => {
      if (err) { throw new Error('This is error'); }
   });
```

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't thought that Mongo works asynchronous. At all I don't understand your solution with `await` (like where do the success block goes into?). But `then` and `catch` work well.

Comment: which success block are you talking about ? you can find some more details about try catch with async-await sytax here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await

Comment: I understand but in your `eg:` block, you have defined `async test()` function but where does the resolved variables go? You are catching only `err` but there is no more `db` variable. If I've tried to take my code (where is callback function where is set both `err` and `db` and put `await` before it (+ called in async fction) - it didn't catch anything.