# How to correctly await a promise in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, type-safety

I have some code where I `continue` a loop if a promise rejects or use its result with something that *requires* it to be of the reolved type, as shown in the following example code:

```js
for (const i in bar) {
    let error = false;
    const foo = await somePromise(i)
        .catch(() => { error = true; });
    if (error) continue;
    // Something that requires foo to be resolved here
}
```

My issue is that typescript does not realize that `foo` is correctly resolved at the end (it still thinks it could be `void` due to not correctly resolving, and therefore gives a `2339` error). What is the correct, type-safe way to have typescript realize that this is fine?

The ways I have found to fix it are by stating that `foo` is of type `any`, which is not ideal and my linter doesn't like that, or using `.then`, which also sucks since I'd have to start nesting multiple `.then` statements and functions in my code, leading to massive indentations.

Comment: Use try and catch when using await. Don't mix callback style and await

Comment: Have a look at [Correct Try…Catch Syntax Using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend

```
for (const i in bar) {
    try {
        const foo = await somePromise(i)
        // Something that requires foo to be resolved here
        // break???
    } catch {
        continue
    }
}
```

or indeed `then`, which isn't that ugly and doesn't need more indentation (or even nesting) either:

```
for (const i in bar) {
    const error = await somePromise(i).then(foo => {
        // Something that requires foo to be resolved here
        return false;
    }, err => {
        return true;
    });
    if (!error) {
        // break???
    }
}
```