# How to implement a Promise retry and undo

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm curious on how API retry and timeouts should be implemented.
Sometimes simply awaiting an api call then catching any error that come up isn't sufficient.
If there's a chain of async requests I need to make, like so:

```js
await client
  .callA()
  .then(async () => await callB())
  .then(async () => await callC())
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and if one of the promise fails midchain, I want to attempt to the request again after a few seconds until attempts run out.

This is my attempt at making a retry wrapper.

```js
async function retry (fn, undo, attempts, wait = 5000) {
  await fn().catch(async (err) => {

    console.error(err.message + `\n retrying in ${wait/1000} seconds...`);

    if (attempts !== 0) {
      // async timeout
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(retry(fn, undo, attempts - 1)), wait);
      })
    } else {
      await undo()
    }
  })
}

await retry(calls, undoCalls, 10)
```

`callA -> callB -> callC`

Say `callA()` succeeds, but `callB()` fails, I want the wrapper to retry `callB()` at an interval instead of starting over again.
Then either:

1. `callB()` eventually succeeds within the allowed attempts, move onto `callC()`.
2. `callB()` runs out of attempts, call `undoCallA()` to revert the changes previously made.

Repeat the above until end of chain.

I'd like some insight on how this is implemented or if there's a library that does something similar. Thanks!

Comment: What is not working about your retry method?

Comment: `retry(fn, attempts - 1)` is missing parameter undo, also you are awaiting the promise to resolve (`await calls()`) and then calling `await fn()`. Just pass `calls, undoCalls` as parameter and I guess it will work

Comment: @Jamiec It works for a single call, but it restarts the call chain on fail.

Comment: What if `undoCallA` fails?

Comment: @jns I've updated the code to according to your comment

Comment: @trincot that's a good question. I think if the undo fn is another promise, it should retry. When it exhausted its attempts, it should just log the failure and return.

Comment: Client-side orchestrated transactions should be avoided IMHO.

Comment: `.then(async () => await callB())` is an anti-pattern. it's the same as `.then(_ => callB())`

Answer (score 6):

Functions should be simple and do just one thing. I would start with a generic `sleep` -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
```

Using simple functions we can build more sophisticated ones, like `timeout` -

```js
const timeout = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.race([ p, sleep(ms).then(_ => { throw Error("timeout") }) ])
```

Now let's say we have a task, `myTask` that takes up to 4 seconds to run. It returns successfully if it generates an odd number. Otherwise it rejects, *"X is not odd"* -

```js
async function myTask () {
  await sleep(Math.random() * 4000)
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  if (x % 2 == 0) throw Error(`${x} is not odd`)
  return x
}
```

Now let's say we want to run `myTask` with a `timeout` of two (2) seconds and `retry` a maximum of three (3) times -

```js
retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 2000), 3)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
Error: 48 is not odd (retry 1/3)
Error: timeout (retry 2/3)
79
```

It's possible `myTask` could produce an odd number on the first attempt. Or it's possible that it could exhaust all attempts before emitting a final error -

```
Error: timeout (retry 1/3)
Error: timeout (retry 2/3)
Error: 34 is not odd (retry 3/3)
Error: timeout
Error: failed after 3 retries
```

Now we implement `retry`. We can use a simple `for` loop -

```js
async function retry (f, count = 5, ms = 1000) {
  for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= count; attempt++) {
    try {
      return await f()
    }
    catch (err) {
      if (attempt <= count) {
        console.error(err.message, `(retry ${attempt}/${count})`)
        await sleep(ms)
      }
      else {
        console.error(err.message)
      }
    }
  }
  throw Error(`failed after ${count} retries`)
}
```

Now that we see how `retry` works, let's write a more complex example that retries multiple tasks -

```js
async function pick3 () {
  const a = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("first pick:", a)
  const b = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("second pick:", b)
  const c = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("third pick:", c)
  return [a, b, c]
}

pick3()
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
Error: timeout (retry 1/5)
Error: timeout (retry 2/5)
first pick: 37
Error: 16 is not odd (retry 1/5)
second pick: 13
Error: 60 is not odd (retry 1/5)
Error: timeout (retry 2/5)
third pick: 15
[37,13,15]
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const timeout = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.race([ p, sleep(ms).then(_ => { throw Error("timeout") }) ])

async function retry (f, count = 5, ms = 1000) {
  for (let attempt = 0; attempt <= count; attempt++) {
    try {
      return await f()
    }
    catch (err) {
      if (attempt < count) {
        console.error(err.message, `(retry ${attempt + 1}/${count})`)
        await sleep(ms)
      }
      else {
        console.error(err.message)
      }
    }
  }
  throw Error(`failed after ${count} retries`)
}

async function myTask () {
  await sleep(Math.random() * 4000)
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  if (x % 2 == 0) throw Error(`${x} is not odd`)
  return x
}

async function pick3 () {
  const a = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("first", a)
  const b = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("second", b)
  const c = await retry(_ => timeout(myTask(), 3000))
  console.log("third", c)
  return [a, b, c]
}

pick3()
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

And because `timeout` is decoupled from `retry`, we can achieve different program semantics. By contrast, the following example not timeout individual tasks but will retry if `myTask` returns an even number -

```js
async function pick3 () {
  const a = await retry(myTask)
  const b = await retry(myTask)
  const c = await retry(myTask)
  return [a, b, c]
}
```

And we could now say `timeout` `pick3` if it takes longer than ten (10) seconds, and `retry` the entire pick if it does -

```js
retry(_ => timeout(pick3(), 10000))
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

This ability to combine simple functions in a variety of ways is what makes them more powerful than one big complex function that tries to do everything on its own.

Of course this means we can apply `retry` directly to the example code in your question -

```js
async function main () {
  await retry(callA, ...)
  await retry(callB, ...)
  await retry(callC, ...)
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

You can either apply `timeout` to the individual calls -

```js
async function main () {
  await retry(_ => timeout(callA(), 3000), ...)
  await retry(_ => timeout(callB(), 3000), ...)
  await retry(_ => timeout(callC(), 3000), ...)
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Or apply `timeout` to each `retry` -

```js
async function main () {
  await timeout(retry(callA, ...), 10000)
  await timeout(retry(callB, ...), 10000)
  await timeout(retry(callC, ...), 10000)
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Or maybe apply `timeout` to the entire process -

```js
async function main () {
  await retry(callA, ...)
  await retry(callB, ...)
  await retry(callC, ...)
  return "done"
}

timeout(main(), 30000).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Or any other combination that matches your actual intention!

Answer (score 0):

I just wouldn't be trying to chain these together. It gets too complex too  quickly, instead have a simpler `retry` logic, and use `try...catch` to determine if something went wrong and call the appropriate `undo` method. Kind of in this pattern

```
await retry(callA, 10, 5000)
try{
  await retry(callB, 10, 5000);
}
catch {
   await undoCallA()
}
```

The `retry` method for this pattern can be much simpler, just retrying for the number of attempts allowed and rejecting if that number is exhausted. This will then raise an error back to the caller allowing it to be `catch`ed.

A simple example:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms));

async function retry(fn, attempts, wait = 1000) {
  let count=0;
  while(count++<attempts) {
     try{        
        const result = await fn();
        return result;
     }
     catch(e){
       if(count == attempts){
          console.log("throw");
          throw e;
       }
       await delay(wait);
       console.log("retry");
     }         
  }
}


function callA(){
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    if(Math.random() < 0.6) reject("random fail A");
    else resolve("CallA")
  })
}

async function undoCallA(){ console.log("Undo A") }

function callB(){
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    if(Math.random() < 0.99) reject("random fail B");
    else resolve("CallB")
  })
}

(async function(){
  console.log(await retry(callA,10));
  
  try{
    console.log(await retry(callB,10))  
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    await undoCallA();  
  }
  
})()
```

Comment: "*I just wouldn't be trying to chain these together*" - well your first snippet can also trivially be written as a chain: `retry(callA, 10, 5000).then(() => retry(callB, 10, 5000).catch(undoCallA))`.

Comment: @Bergi it's true, I just think it gets complex with `C` also, which presumably needs to undo A & B. I would much rather have some simple try..catch logic there.

Comment: `.then()` can easily express the same as nested  `try`/`catch` blocks - `retry(callA, 10, 5000).then(() => retry(callB, 10, 5000).then(() => retry(callC, 10, 5000).catch(undoCallB)).catch(undoCallA))` should work fine (assuming that `undoCallX` do rethrow the error passed to them). But I'd even argue that [`.then()` is more powerful than `try`/`catch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-axios-retry-forked-8fi5f?file=/src/index.js) that uses a [custom Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

const callA = async () => console.log(`Call A`);
const callB = async () => {
  console.log(`Call B`);
  throw Error("ooops");
};
const callC = async () => console.log(`Call C`);

const undoA = async () => console.log(`Undo A`);
const undoB = async () => console.log(`Undo B`);
const undoC = async () => console.log(`Undo C`);

const promise = CPromise.retry(() => callA())
  .finally((v, isRejected) => isRejected && undoA())
  .then(() =>
    CPromise.retry(() => callB()).finally(
      (v, isRejected) => isRejected && undoB()
    )
  )
  .then(() =>
    CPromise.retry(() => callC()).finally(
      (v, isRejected) => isRejected && undoC()
    )
  )

  .then(
    (v) => console.log(`Done: ${v}`),
    (err) => console.error(`Fail: ${err}`)
  );

// promise.pause()
// promise.resume()
// promise.cancel()
```

Console log:

```
Call A 
Call B 
Call B 
Call B 
Undo B 
Error: ooops
```

[One more example with retrying the axios request::](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-axios-retry-esr00)

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

CPromise.retry(
  (attempt) => {
    console.log(`Attempt [${attempt}]`);
    return cpAxios(url).timeout(attempt * 1000 + 500);
  },
  { retries: 3, delay: (attempt) => attempt * 1000 }
).then(
  (response) => console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`),
  (err) => console.warn(`Fail: ${err}`)
);
```