# How to intercept error on a Promise with async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

On a NodeJs project, I call my async function this way:

```
const response = await myFunction();
```

Here's the definition of the function:

```
myFunction = async () => {
    return await new Promise((next, fail) => {
        // ...

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: apiEndpoint,
            data: payload
        }).then(function (response) {
            // ...

            next(orderId);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            fail(error);
        });
    });
}
```

How should I correctly intercept an error if that's happens? i.e. how I manage it when I await the function?

EDIT: as requested, a more complete snippet:

```
import express from 'express';
import { helpers } from '../helpers.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/createOrder', helpers.restAuthorize, async (req, res) => {
    // ...
    const orderId = await api.createOrder();
    let order = {
        buyOrderId: orderId
    }
    
    const placed = await api.checkPlaced(orderId);
    if (placed) {
        let ack = await api.putAck(orderId);
        order.checksum = placed.checksum;
        order.ack = ack;
    }

    InternalOrder.create(order, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: error });
        } else {
            res.json("ok");
        }
    })
})

export { router as exchangeRouter }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `return await new Promise` is unneeded here? If you're using async/await you shouldn't need `.then` at all. consider using try/catch

Comment: Have you tried `try { ... } catch( err ) { ... }` ? Iirc, that works when `await`ing stuff.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Correct Try...Catch Syntax Using Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572), but I'm not quite sure what you are asking. What do you want to do with the "intercepted" error?

Comment: @Bergi the then() solution is horrible to manage when you have a cascade of function that need to execute one after the other...

Comment: @markzzz It would help if you could post your actual code then

Comment: @Bergi: added a minimal example. Of course the amount of chain call could be increase on other section. The imporant is that each function will execute one after the other (both have new Promise). What I need to manage is an eventual error on each function (returning a sort of res.status(500) in case of error).

Comment: @markzzz You don't need to write any `try`/`catch` yourself for that, [Express 5 will by default handle the promise rejection of the `async` route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) and will send a 500 error.

Comment: @Bergi what if I need to manage the exception? Such as not return 500, or filter error data and do different action, and so on...

Comment: @markzzz Then just write a `try`/`catch` block around the part from which you want to handle the error. But I still don't see how you'd have 4 nested blocks because of that.

Comment: btw, you should really promisify that `InternalOrder.create` call

Comment: @Bergi not able to catch the error. Is it correct to do that fail(error)?

Comment: Not able to catch which error? What are the `api` methods and `InternalOrder.create`, where and how are they defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246022/discussion-between-markzzz-and-bergi).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use try/catch:

```
let response;
try {
   response = await myFunction();
} catch (error) {
  // Handle error here.
}
```

Comment: if I have lots of async/await call in chain, this will flood the nested blocks within each try catch, which I don't like...

Comment: @markzzz Are you really *handling* that many different errors in nested blocks?

Comment: @Bergi I'm handling 3/4 call on a chain. 4 nested block are not so good imo