# Why does await/async not work properly when I pass a function into .exec()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm trying to use await to wait for a database lookup using mongoose and save the response to a variable. For some reason, when I pass a function to .exec(), then await doesn't seem to work.

Way that doesn't work:

```
    var document = await Collection.findOne({ 'num': num }).populate('field').exec((err, result) => {
            if (err) throw error
    })
    console.log(document) // undefined
```

Way that does work:

```
    var document = await Collection.findOne({ 'num': num }).populate('field').exec()
    console.log(document) // The document I want
```

I don't think the population is what is causing the problem because I tried the code without the population and it worked.
Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: You don't return result in your first callback, so it's discarded

Comment: I just tried returning result and it didn't work for me. Perhaps I'm not doing it right. Do you just put return result in the callback as follows: .exec((err, result) => {
            return result
    })
console.log(result) // undefined

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 5.13.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [documented behaviour of *mongodb*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/):

> NOTE
> If you specify a callback, the method *does not* return a Promise.

<sup>(Emphasis theirs)</sup>

Also [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/):

> **NOTE**: All the examples below use async/await syntax.
>
> However, all async API calls support an optional callback as the final
> argument, if a callback is provided a Promise will not be returned.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Do you know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Just don't use a callback, use the way that does work!

Comment: True, true;). Let's say I wanted to do something with that error, would there be a way to do that? I guess I could always put the whole thing into a try catch block.

Comment: That, or `….exec().catch(err => { … })`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await).

Comment: I like your options. Thank you