# is it good practice to use try inside try block to catch different errors? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I am using try catch inside try block to print relative message or get to know in which method error happened.

code snippet

```js
  for (const searchUrl of savedSearchUrls) {
    console.log("here");
    // function will get all the links of profiles in saved search url
    try {
      const links = await scrapeFromurl(browser, searchUrl);
      try {
        saveToDatabase(links);
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e, "eror while saving to database");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      handleError(err, "error in scrapeFromurl()");
    }
  }
```

I have searched on google but couldn't find related topic.

what are the other ways to accomplish similar things?
what are the best practice to handle this type of situation.

Comment: If all you are going to do is handle each exception the same way, you can actually just use the uncaughtexception handler in window. Try / catch an exception if you are going to handle it in a specific way

Comment: I am using linux OS. Moreover, can you elaborate your point a little bit. I am beginner.

Comment: Yes it is good practice, you can throw a general error in main catch and specific errors for specific operation in inner catches.

Comment: Is `saveToDatabase` asynchronous as well?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await

Comment: Thank @Bergi for your response. saveToDatabase is not asynchronous. I mean this function is not declared as async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a single try-catch block is enough without needs for nesting other try-catches into it. However, there may be some legitimate exceptions from these rules.

## Exception 1: Different handlers for the same exception

Let's consider the following example

```
try {
  myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
  } else {
    // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
  }
}
```

It is perfectly possible that inside your `try` there is a section where a given error type, like a `RangeError` needs a different way of handling than the main `catch`. In this case it might make sense to have another try-catch inside your try, albeit, in this case, for better readability it would make sense to consider the inner try as a method and call that, so you would not physically nest the try-catch blocks, but separate the concerns of the try-catches into separate methods.

## Exception 2: Handling a certain type of error only at a section of a try-block

It is quite possible that you want your try-catch to throw the error further in the majority of your `try` block, but, in a specific section you want it to handle it. Again, in this case it would make sense to separate the inner `try` into its own method.

## Conclusion

Having nested try-catches are nonintuitive for a reader, therefore it makes sense to separate the inner `try` into its own method whenever you encounter the need to nest tries. Yet, as the examples above show, there are legitimate needs to drift away from the outer handling of an error for some sections. However, by default it is a good idea to consider such sections as separate concerns worthy of separating from the method. Of course, sometimes you might want to keep nested try-catches without separating their concerns, but more often than not it is worth to apply the separations. So, a rule of thumb that you may want to consider is to refactor nested try-catches either into separate methods or a single try-catch, **unless there is a very good reason not to do so**.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using only one try catch block and specific error instances for each method, then in catch block you can simply check which method throws an error by using `instanceof` operator

```js
class ScrapeError extends Error {
  message = "error in scrapeFromurl()"
}

class DBError extends Error {
  message = "eror while saving to database"
}

async function scrapeFromurl() {
  throw new ScrapeError();
}

async function saveToDatabase(links) {
  throw new DBError();
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const links = await scrapeFromurl();
    await saveToDatabase(links);
  } catch (e) {
  
    if (e instanceof ScrapeError) {
      console.log('scrape', e);
    }
    
    if (e instanceof DBError) {
      console.log('dberror', e);
    }
    
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: I didn't think about this. it will be useful. Don't you think that it's overkill that we are defining custom error for each error?

Comment: @Mike your `catch` block is missing an `else throw e;` if you meant to handle only those two error classes

Comment: @KashifGhafoor Yes, it might be overkill to define separate classes for them. All you need to do is put enough information in the error object to be able to distinguish them appropriately later, that can also be a `.code` or `.httpStatus` property. And you might not even need to distinguish them if they already have the appropriate error message on them.

Answer (score -1):

In asyncronous scripts you can use domains for error handling. And trycatch in trycatch can be treated like domain in domain, which is pointless.
Moreover, programmers always tend to prevent the code from growing horizontally like this

```
{
  ...
  {
    ...
    {
      ... (and so on)
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So it is a really bad idea. I can keep on telling drawbacks of this approach, but not going to. Just use one trycatch with switchcase inside to handle all errors

Comment: No, you don't use domains for error handling.