# Proper implementation of try-catch in nest js regarding exceptions

Tags: javascript, error-handling, nestjs

I want to implement service logic of fetching an item by its id from a database in try-catch construction. If an item with such id doesn't exist, then I want to throw 404, else if I have some server error/unexpected behavior - 500. My service implementation is as the following:

```
  async fetchItem(id: string): Promise<Item> {
    try {
      const item = await this.ItemsRepository.findOneBy({ id });
      if (!item)
        throw new HttpException("Item wasn't found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); // here I want to stop function execution
      return item;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }
```

The problem is if the item doesn't exist, I get 500 status code.

As far as I understood, if I throw an error in `try` block, then I automatically go to `catch` block. I thought about moving 404 exception to `catch` block but I don't think it's a good idea as I might have server problem and the status won't be suitable. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
async fetchItem(id: string): Promise<Item> {
  const item = await this.ItemsRepository.findOneBy({ id }).catch(err => {
    throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  });
  if (!item) {
    throw new HttpException("Item wasn't found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  return item;
}
```

Doing the same with `try`/`catch` is [possible but ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await).