# Marking a try / catch as async in TypeScript / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am having problems getting the below code to go into the catch block on error,

```
try {
    this.doSomething();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

if "doSomething" returns a promise / runs asynchronous code.

```
doSomething() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.MySubscription = this.myService.fetchUserDataFromDB().subscribe({
            next: (val: any) => {
                this.userData = val

                resolve()
            }, error: (error) => {
                let uiErrorMsg = 'Failed to fetch user data';
                let consoleErrorMsg = 'Error occurred when calling backend API fetchUserDataFromDB';
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    consoleErrorMsg += ` | Status: ${error.status} ${error.statusText} | URL: ${error.url}`;
                }
                const consoleError = new Error(consoleErrorMsg);

                if(error?.status != 401) {
                    const data = [{ title: 'Alert', message: [uiErrorMsg] }, { okButtonTitle: 'Close' }]
                    let dialogRef: any = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationModalComponent, {data});
                    // await firstValueFrom(dialogRef.afterClosed())
                }

                reject(consoleError);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Some places I need to call `this.doSomething()` not caring exactly when it finishes, other places I do care, and in those cases put the word `await` in front when I want the code to wait until it finishes before it proceeds to the next line.

```
await this.doSomething();
```

There is apparently a way to catch the errors of a promise without awaiting for it, but it's in a different syntax:

```
this.doSomething().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

So where I need to wait for it to finish I use try/catch with "await" as one would expect, but when I don't care when it finishes I am needing to call it with ".catch()"  instead of try/catch to catch the errors.

Is there any plan to allow marking a try block as async, so that we can keep try/catch syntax in both scenarios, so we don't need two different syntaxes and can be more consistent with other programming languages where try/catches reliably go in the catch blocks when they are expected to?

Such as something like

```
try async {
    this.doSomething()
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

and

```
try {
    await this.doSomething()
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

respectively?

Luckily the purpose of my try catch was simply to handle printing of error messages in a visually pleasing manner. But I can imagine this causing a lot of frustration for someone who was relying on their catch block being entered regardless of whether they called their function with "await" or not.

**Is there a way to make a try/catch asynchronous or do we need to maintain both .catch() syntax and try/catch syntax?**

(I am using TypeScript 4.9.5, rxjs 7.8.1)

Comment: There is not a way, and I would not expect there to be a way any time soon.

Comment: Also: *not caring exactly when it finishes* — you actually **do** care, because you want to deal with the error. Just use `await` all the time.

Comment: "Is there any plan to allow marking a try block as async" AFAIK, no. The process of adding things to ECMAScript is open, though, so monitor it yourself: https://github.com/tc39/proposals.

Comment: Note that, if you don't care about the result of an async function, it's slightly odd to care about the error. If you just want to catch the error and display a message, or emit a log entry, see [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event). You can handle *all* uncaught asynchronous exceptions this way.

Comment: Either use `await` so the rejection at the `await` will go into the `catch` block OR get rid of the `try/catch` and use `.catch()` so you handle the reject case.  If you don't want the remaining code to wait for the promise to resolve/reject, then just use `.catch()`.  It works just fine.  There is no way to make `try/catch` catch a rejected promise that you aren't using `await` on.  The language doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the reason you don't want to use `await` is that you don't want to make the rest of the code block wait for `doSomething()` to finish.

I recommend you always use `await` and never `.then()`/`.catch()`, and instead use an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    await this.doSomething()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})()
// ... code here should run without waiting for `doSomething()` to complete
```

Now, the synchronous beginning of the `doSomething()` function will execute immediately, and as soon as there is an `await` inside the `doSomething()` function, execution of the rest of the original code block will continue without waiting for the `doSomething()` function to complete.

You could avoid the IIFE like this:

```js
async doSomething2() {
  try {
    await this.doSomething()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

this.doSomething2()
// ... code here should run without waiting for `doSomething()` to complete
```

If you mostly want to do this for the purpose of logging errors to the console, you could create a helper function like this:

```js
async function backgroundExec(f) {
  try {
    await f()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

// ... later on:

backgroundExec(() => this.doSomething())
```

Comment: Ah. So this way we keep the try/catch, but still have somewhat odd looking syntax with `(async () => {` and `})()`

Comment: Why do you advise against .catch()?

Comment: @the_overflowing_stack Yes, I added in an alternative approach that doesn't use IIFEs. IIFEs are quite common, so they only look odd if you're not used to them. I recommend against then/catch because the reason that `await` was added to Javascript was because then/catch code was often messy and error-prone.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer, I'd prefer to not declare functions in the same scope that they are being called. Can I avoid this by putting the word "async" before my function name that returns the promise `doSomething()` and then calling `doSomething()` with `await` without needing the `})()` syntax, would that successfully not make the rest of the code wait for it to finish?

Comment: If you alter the doSomething() function declaration to be `async doSomething()`, you still have the problem that you need to await it in order to use a try/catch block. It therefore doesn't help.

Comment: @the_overflowing_stack Fundamentally, there is no such thing as marking a code block (which is not a function) as async, and then choosing whether to await that code block or not. There are only async functions.

Comment: @the_overflowing_stack I added in a backgroundExec helper, which neatens the code

Comment: @AndrewParks I actually [do recommend `.then()`/`.catch()` *for error handling*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await), it is often simpler/cleaner and allows to express the desired semantics better

Comment: @Bergi the reason I personally don't like it is that if people only use then/catch occasionally, they are more likely to introduce a bug. An example that stuck in my mind is when a promise resolves as rejected, and `.catch(x).then(y)` causes both x and y to be called. This happened because someone started with a simple `.catch()`, and afterwards someone else tried to make the code slightly more complex

Comment: @AndrewParks I wouldn't say it's "more likely", assuming one has a decent understanding of how things work. If you want to avoid `x` and `y` both being called, neither `p.catch(x).then(y)` nor `p.then(y).catch(x)` nor `try { y(await p) } catch(e) { x(e) }` will work, you need `p.then(y, x)`.