# Async/await, throwing error again in catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I guess that it becomes more and more standard to use `try/catch` syntax to handle any kind of rejections when using `async/await`.

But what if you have something potentitally rejecting inside a `catch` block?

This wouldn't increase nested level, but it won't work:

```
// Won't work!
try {
  await Promise.reject()
} catch (e) {
  console.log('caught rejection')
  await Promise.reject()
} catch (e) {
  console.log('caught rejection again')
}
```

This seems like a correct way of handling this, this works OK, but it's harder to read and has potential for nested `try/catch` hell:

```
try {
  await Promise.reject()
} catch (e) {
  console.log('caught rejection')
  try {
    await Promise.reject()
  } catch(e2) {
    console.log('caught rejection again')
  }
}
```

Can this case be an argument against `try/catch` syntax and in favor of old `.then()/.catch()` syntax? Or maybe there are other, nicer ways to handle situtations like that?

```
Promise.reject()
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('caught rejection')
    return Promise.reject()
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log('caught rejection again')
  })
```

Comment: *"Can this case be an argument against try/catch syntax and in favor of old .then()/.catch() syntax?"* calls for opinion, which is specifically off-topic here. Similarly, *"Or maybe there are other, nicer ways to handle situtations like that?"* is extremely open-ended. If you want to use promise functions rather than `try`/`catch`, you're free to do that. If you don't, you have the same situation as any other `try`/`catch`, where yes, errors thrown in the `catch` aren't caught by a subsequent `catch`, you'd have to nest.

Comment: opinion-based...

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback. I'm fully ok with closing or deleting the question, but nevertheless I wonder what is a good place to discuss this problem.

Comment: what I can tell, is you need to understand in your first example why the second catch wouldnt, work, so it makes sense to have it nested. Also you could do it in a more modular way with Promise.catch() itself. so you need to keep the reference for the exisiting promiese to have it reusable

Comment: "*I guess that it becomes more and more standard to use `try/catch` syntax to handle any kind of rejections when using `async/await`.*" - not sure what you mean. You still [should use `.catch(…)` or `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572) when it makes more sense to do so. They behave differently than `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score -1):

If you structure your code as a queue there's no need in nested `try/catch`:

```html
<script type="module">

await queue([() => Promise.reject(), () => Promise.reject(), () => Promise.resolve()]);

console.log('trying unsuccessful queue');

try{
  await queue([() => Promise.reject(), () => Promise.reject(), () => Promise.reject()]);
} catch (e){
  console.log(e.message);
}

async function queue(tries){

  let idx = -1, fetch;

  while(fetch = tries[++idx]){
    try {
      await fetch();
      console.log('finally resolved, thank god');
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('caught rejection');
      if(idx === tries.length - 1){
        throw new Error('The queue was unsuccessful');        
      }
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: "*you are trying to implement an async queue*" - huh? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Bergi removed that, but left the second statement that could be a plausible solution in some cases