# Async / Await breaking execution and returning 403 from express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Assuming node.js LTS and use of async await, what is the proper way to break execution?  I'll display a promisified version and an async / await version to demonstrate the issue -

In the async / await version if an error is thrown from `checkUserRouteRequirements` for example and `403` is sent back from the API express continues code execution and tries to `res.json(result);` as well.

I would rather have the `.catch` be in the `validateRoute` method for re-usability since there are possibly hundreds of routes, and of course not have the error for trying to send headers twice.

### Async / Await

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  await validateRoute(roles.Approved, req, res, next);
  // await does not break code execution
  const result = await channelsService.getAll();

  return res.json(result);
});

async function validateRoute(role, req, res, next) {
  return checkUserRouteRequirements(req.user.sub, role).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).json({});
  });
}
```

### Promisified

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  validateRoute(roles.Approved, req, res, next).then(() => {
    channelsService.getAll().then(result => { return res.json(result) });
  });
});

function validateRoute(role, req, res, next) {
  return checkUserRouteRequirements(req.user.sub, role).catch(error => {
    res.status(403).json({});
  });
}
```

I am not a fan of putting try / catches everywhere either and throwing errors that have to be caught.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Uh, in your promisified version it "*continues code execution*" to `channelsService.getAll()` and `res.json(result)` as well! You just should not put the `catch` in the middle of the promise chain - it's like putting more code after `try`/`catch`, it will always run.

Comment: I recommend to use a [wrapper around the `async function`]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349331/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-await-async-try-catch-block-to-every-function/41350872#41350872) which handles the errors for you - so that you can use `throw` whenever you like, and don't need to spell out `try`/`catch` everywhere.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so the `.then` never is called because on the same promise the `catch` is called since the promise is returned.  Just verified in console - 
```
let promiseTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { console.log('promise'); setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('test') },1) }).then(() => { console.log('then') }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: I may be wrong though since this is in express and I was just putting together some pseudocode.  Putting error handling wrappers though seems like it's even worse considering express' use of middleware and it would kind of be circumventing all of the real error handling, right?

Comment: Your `then` and `catch` callbacks are not on the *same* promise, they are chained to each other. And they are chained in the wrong order: compare `Promise.reject("error").then(() => console.log("never happens")).catch(console.log)` against `Promise.reject("error").catch(console.log).then(() => console.log("runs after the error was handled"))`.

Comment: The error handling wrapper I recommended only helps to avoid the boilerplate, it does make use of the "real error handling".

Comment: Well how would the wrapper be able to call the correct `next` and such without being hacky?

Comment: Exactly as in the second snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350872/1048572)