# How can I use async lambdas without a try/catch block and still have custom error messages?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, async-await

I'm trying to avoid wrapping all my awaited calls in an async lambda with a try catch. I want to catch and send custom error responses, but wrapping each awaited call in a try/catch is syntactically ugly compared to `.catch()`.  Is there a way to do something like this:

```
exports.hanlder = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const foo = await bar(baz).catch((error) => {
    eventResponse.statusCode = 503;
    eventResponse.body = JSON.stringify({ message: 'unable to bar' , error});
    // normally we'd callback(null, eventResponse)
  });
```

Without wrapping in try/catch like this?

```
exports.hanlder = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let foo;
  try {
    foo = await bar(baz);
  } catch (error) {
     eventResponse.statusCode = 503;
     eventResponse.body = JSON.stringify({ message: 'unable to bar', error});
     return eventResponse;
  }
  // then do something else with foo

  if (foo.whatever) {
     // some more async calls
  }
```

It's just not pretty to have a bunch of try/catch once you have like 7 awaited calls in a single lambda. Is there a prettier way to do it using the promise built-in `.catch()`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.catch()` just fine together with `await` - it returns a promise.

Comment: Bergi, but i can't return the eventResponse in the catch because that returns in the catch block and not for the whole lambda.

Comment: At this point, why not using all promises ?

Comment: ew, you mean having layers-deep of promise chains?

Comment: Don't ew that, it's down to preference. I personnally enjoy it

Comment: The whole point is I'm refactoring to get rid of dozens of chained `then()`s because it is completely unreadable.

Comment: Just create an async handler function that get re-used again.   I do this for handling express routing, as the routing is callback based, but I like to use promises..

Answer (score 3):

[The `.catch()` method is compatible with `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await) and often less ugly if you want to rethrow an exception. I think you're looking for

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    const foo = await bar(baz).catch(error => {
      throw {message: 'unable to bar', error};
    });
    // do something with `foo`, and more `await`ing calls throwing other errors
    // return a response
  } catch(err) {
    eventResponse.statusCode = 503;
    eventResponse.body = JSON.stringify(err);
    return eventResponse;
  }
};
```

Comment: ah great, don't know why i totally forgot I could just re-throw it. Then I assume the lambda just makes the error message the response content.

Comment: Yes, I would've expected that, I just wasn't sure whether your goal was to set a custom status code etc as well. You might be able to omit the `try`/`catch` block and just let the lamda runner handle the error.

Comment: dang, i think i have to still use the try / catch. if i just throw with the intended message, i get the 'unhandled promise rejection'.

Comment: @FlavorScape Aw, I would've hoped for more in a lambda, but you still can [use your own wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41349331/1048572) to deal with the error handling so that you just write `exports.handler = handleErrors(async(event, context) { … });`

Comment: yeah you'd think they'd just internally have re-thrown errors emit the response with the message of the re-thrown error, just as the callback does.... sigh