# await on request in post

Tags: javascript, typescript, nats.io

how can I await this `nc.request` and send the result

here is my post code

```
app.post('/sum',(req,res)=> {

    let result   
    nc.request('my.request', {x: 2, y:3 }, {max: 1}, resp => {
        console.log("Response from subscriber: " + resp)
        result = resp
    })
    res.status(200).send(result)
    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have the result inside your `nc.request` callback, so you can likely send your response from inside that callback.

```js
app.post('/sum',(req,res)=> {
    nc.request('my.request', {x: 2, y:3 }, {max: 1}, resp => {
        console.log("Response from subscriber: " + resp)
        // Send here, since you have the response
        res.status(200).send(resp)
    })    
})
```

However, if `nc.request` returns a Promise containing the response data, you can await it inside an async function.

```js
app.post('/sum', async (req,res, next)=> {
    try {
        const result = await nc.request('my.request', {x: 2, y:3 }, {max: 1})

        console.log("Response from subscriber: " + result)
        res.status(200).send(result)
    }
    catch (err) {
        // Have express handle errors from the async function
        next(err)
    }

})
```

Comment: Will `app.post` properly deal with promise rejections if you use an `async` function?

Comment: Looks like it won't automatically, however [you can pass all caught errors to express next function](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#catching-errors) in order to have express handle them like normal. Inside an async function, you can handle rejections from `nc.request` using try/catch just like normal. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#Adding_error_handling) for details. I'll update the async function's code to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Alternatively you can [write a wrapper function to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349331/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-await-async-try-catch-block-to-every-function/41350872#41350872)

Answer (score 0):

This way it should work:

```
app.post('/sum', async (req,res)=> {
    let result =  await nc.request('my.request', {x: 2, y:3 }, {max: 1});   
    res.status(200).send(result)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `nc.request()` returns a promise? And will `app.post` properly handle rejections?

Comment: I saw that they were using it in their documentation so im pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `res.status(200).send(resp)` into the callback function, because you can get the result of the request inside the callback function.

```
app.post('/sum',(req,res)=> {
    nc.request('my.request', {x: 2, y:3 }, {max: 1}, resp => {
        console.log("Response from subscriber: " + resp)
        res.status(200).send(resp)
    })
})
```