# ES6 way to wrap every express controller in a try catch block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, composition

I have an express app that has controllers that look like this:

```
export const createObject = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...do stuff
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
export const updateObject = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...do stuff
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
... etc
```

is there a fancy ES6 way to wrap every one of those calls in the try-catch block? I want to do something like:

```
const tryCatchWrapper = (f, res, code) => {
  return () => {
    try {
      return f.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(code).json(e);
    }
  };
};
export const createObject = tryCatchWrapper(async (req, res) => {
    ...do stuff
  }
}, res, 500);
```

but I'm not quite sure how to construct/compose this.

Comment: That `tryCatchWrapper` you've shown **is** written in ES6 arrow function syntax already. What else do you want?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349331/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-an-await-async-try-catch-block-to-every-function/) answer your question? It uses ES8 though.

Comment: @Bergi I think I am close, but how do I pass the res into the try catch wrapper so that it can handle the response? my code above doesn't actually work since the res is not available when passed in to the wrapper

Comment: You don't pass it into `tryCatchWrapper`. It's a parameter to the returned function - use `return (req, res, next) => { try { await f(req, res, next) …`.

Comment: Btw `.apply(this, arguments)` doesn't work with an arrow function

Comment: removing the arrow functions and using named parameters as you mentioned worked @Bergi